# Unable to source .profile in shell script

Tags: python, bash, shell

To start off, I am a complete noob to Debian, Python, and shell scripts, so please speak to me like I am a toddler.

I have a python script I am running through a virtualenv, and I want to execute it via a shell script. Here is what I'm typing in to the terminal to do so:

`source .profile
workon cv
cd Desktop/Camera
python main.py`

I tried turning this into a shell script, but I receive the error -- `source: not found`

I've found no answer to my problem, at least not in any terms I can understand. Any advice would be appreciated. Furthermore, before you answer, I also have no idea why it is I need to execute `source .profile`, I'm simply following a beginner guide for the project which can be found here: `https://www.hackster.io/hackerhouse/smart-security-camera-90d7bd`

Thanks in advance, and sorry if this is a dumb question.

Comment: is `source: not found` really the error message you're seing? Is it not `source: no such file or directory: .profile`?

Comment: `pi@raspberrypi:~/Desktop $ sh shell.sh

shell.sh: 4: shell.sh: source: not found
`

(it won't let me format this better, sorry.)

Comment: Try to replace `source` with a dot. That is: `. .profile`

Comment: source ~/.profile  as it says on the link . Remember the tilde(~)

Comment: @janos

shell.sh: 3: .: .profile: not found

Comment: you are not following closely the program you linked to. In the doc you linked to the first line reads `source /home/pi/.profile`, instead you wrote `source .profile`. You are probably not in your home directory when starting the script, so you need to also supply the directory where .profile is, which would be `/home/pi` in your case

Comment: @NikhilFadnis

I use source .profile when just executing it in a terminal and it works. However, I tried changing it to source ~/.profile in the shell script and the result is the same error :(

Comment: you don't have to have `.profile`... it's one of many options you might have. i am more interested in that your shell does not support `source`. what shell are you using? try `echo $SHELL`.

Comment: @hansaplast Just tried that as well, same result as before. Source: not found. Tried doing `cd /home/pi/        source .profile` as well, no luck.

Comment: I think you've completely ignored the referred howto which creates `.profile` and much more: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/04/18/install-guide-raspberry-pi-3-raspbian-jessie-opencv-3/

Comment: What does `ls -l ~/.profile` get you?

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr

echo $SHELL resulted in a response of /bin/bash

Comment: Run `bash shell.sh `

Comment: then what `bash --version` gives? since you are dealing with embedded system, i guess you are messing around with busybox, aren't you?

Comment: @codeforester `-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi 792 Nov  8 20:52 /home/pi/.profile`

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr `GNU bash, version 4.4.12(1)-release` No idea what busybox is.

Comment: @NikhilFadnis Woo! A combination of doing cd /home/pi before source .profile and executing it as bash shell.sh instead of sh shell.sh worked. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Adding as answer, accept awaited !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best practice for Shell would be shebang at the begging like @Veda suggested.

Execute the shell script using bash like `bash shell.sh` as the link suggests using relative locations rather than absolute ones

Answer (score 0):

Add a hashbang at the top of your script (should be the first line):

```
#!/bin/bash
```

This will ensure you are running your shell-script in bash. Having a shell does not mean it's bash. Not all shells have the `source` function that you are using (bash has it).

Some prefer the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

Since you are a "beginner" I think it does not really matter. The first makes sure it's using the bash in /bin, the second is using the PATH variable to find bash, so the user of your script can provide it's own bash if he/she wants.